# How to get image element on XML document with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, rss

I'm trying to get the thumbnail links like:

```
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/38/8f/c9/388fc91621d9d12db3d1211b39ab0fc1--flying-dog-pure-joy.jpg
```

But for some reason getElementsByTagName doesn't return what I wanted.

```
$newdom=new DOMDocument();
$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.pinterest.co.uk/sucastro/animals.rss");
$newdom->loadXML($xml);
$out=$newdom->getElementsByTagName('img');
print_r($out);
```

I also tried

```
$out=$newdom->channel->item->description->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

which also failed.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 2.0
        )

    [channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [title] => ANIMALS
            [link] => https://www.pinterest.com/sucastro/animals/
            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [language] => en-us
            [lastBuildDate] => Fri, 48 Jan 2017 33:33:33 +0000
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [title] => Hi ladies. Let's pin
                            [link] => https://www.pinterest.com/pin/209628557639623067/
                            [description] => <a href="/pin/209628557639623067/"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/38/8f/c9/388fc91621d9d12db3d1211b39ab0fc1--flying-dog-pure-joy.jpg"></a>Hi ladies. Let&#39;s pin GREEN AND WHITE today ❤️
                            [pubDate] => Fri, 08 Sep 2017 20:04:02 +0000
                            [guid] => https://www.pinterest.com/pin/209628557639623067/
                        )
```

I have looked around for hours trying different things, but for some reason it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking to using XML and XPath, which is possible, but you have to decode each block as you read it - so it's not as efficient as it could have been.
The code reads the RSS feed and then fetches all of the description elements.

It then decodes the encoded HTML and fetches the src attribute from each segment.

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

libxml_use_internal_errors();
$doc = simplexml_load_file("https://www.pinterest.co.uk/sucastro/animals.rss");
$items = $doc->xpath("//item/description");
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML(html_entity_decode($item));
    $img = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
    echo $img->getAttribute('src').PHP_EOL;

}
```

This outputs (truncated for space)...

```
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/38/8f/c9/388fc91621d9d12db3d1211b39ab0fc1--flying-dog-pure-joy.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/d7/1f/dc/d71fdc7f19d8c4b896840e4d8c65642f.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/94/2a/fb/942afb5bab44f6f3b4b9ea4f35690c54--national-forest-cute-photos.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/cc/3c/26/cc3c2658f23571a8eb34a0e34d71e80a--majestic-animals-lion-cub.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/98/1f/c6/981fc6e5e1e332e0067c1b6748fce20a--swan-lake-birds-.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/86/90/8d/86908dd2ce9b8c73648cdcbc5d3325e1--white-bunnies-white-rabbits.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e0/7b/ce/e07bcea2ec026b5900afd0dc0c35ef71--autumn-leaves-west-highland-terrier.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/8f/87/e9/8f87e95b0384a0f227c9078d053cc202--new-friends-my-friend.jpgls-lion-cub.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/98/1f/c6/981fc6e5e1e332e0067c1b6748fce20a--swan-lake-birds-.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/86/90/8d/86908dd2ce9b8c73648cdcbc5d3325e1--white-bunnies-white-rabbits.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e0/7b/ce/e07bcea2ec026b5900afd0dc0c35ef71--autumn-leaves-west-highland-terrier.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/8f/87/e9/8f87e95b0384a0f227c9078d053cc202--new-friends-my-friend.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You have things a bit mixed up. You get the feed into an `SimpleXMLElement`, but then try to load it to a `DOMDocument`.

What you need to do is grab your `SimpleXMLElement`, iterate through the `item`s, and get their description. Note that you *can't* use XPath or related here (other than making it be another SimpleXMLElement) to get the source of the `img`, since now you're dealing with just the value of the element.

So, what you *can* do here is see if there is an image, and if there is, extract the source:

```
<?php
$newdom=new DOMDocument();
$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.pinterest.co.uk/sucastro/animals.rss");
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    $desc = $item->description;
    if (preg_match("/<img src=\"(.*?)\"/i", $desc, $m)) {
        echo "Image: ".$m[1]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply fetches the images from the descriptions of rss channels.

You can try this :

```
<?php

$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.pinterest.co.uk/sucastro/animals.rss");
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $item->description, $image);
    echo($image['src']);
    echo "<br/>";
}

?>
```

**Output :**

```
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/38/8f/c9/388fc91621d9d12db3d1211b39ab0fc1--flying-dog-pure-joy.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/d7/1f/dc/d71fdc7f19d8c4b896840e4d8c65642f.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/94/2a/fb/942afb5bab44f6f3b4b9ea4f35690c54--national-forest-cute-photos.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/cc/3c/26/cc3c2658f23571a8eb34a0e34d71e80a--majestic-animals-lion-cub.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/98/1f/c6/981fc6e5e1e332e0067c1b6748fce20a--swan-lake-birds-.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/86/90/8d/86908dd2ce9b8c73648cdcbc5d3325e1--white-bunnies-white-rabbits.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e0/7b/ce/e07bcea2ec026b5900afd0dc0c35ef71--autumn-leaves-west-highland-terrier.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/8f/87/e9/8f87e95b0384a0f227c9078d053cc202--new-friends-my-friend.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/5e/8f/3b/5e8f3bc079c7617d8cf3a91568f402cd--love-my-dog-puppy-love.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/9f/6a/79/9f6a7948c1cf3d1fbc067d52691bbc7d--water-fountains-bird-baths.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/07/09/d0/0709d0b16178da14facd8401a8472a3d--dachshund-humor-dapple-dachshund.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/2e/c7/af/2ec7af9628a30ec3901c3d14d2b6dc08--animal-portraits-animals-photos.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/06/2e/4b/062e4b396631ae6fc52a64c2f32d8022--cat-whiskers-exotic-cats.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/5e/5c/d6/5e5cd648d4efb29b82607445b795d357--teacups-tea-time.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/dc/30/ce/dc30ce6b41970dc93f1a3607cb48ab2a--pretty-birds-beautiful-birds.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/80/63/e1/8063e102ba108b0f6531065bdf50687c--bear-costume-the-zoo.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/c6/f3/1e/c6f31efadca1b2f71b898a85c46a6f87--baby-polar-bears-panda-bears.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/c2/13/c3/c213c317cc750ac5fef00c4ebd1a1b71--elephant-love-baby-elephants.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/49/75/d8/4975d85611c291c50db1ee57f6018bef.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/6b/cd/35/6bcd353ac7250d4159d3c74fe0d75747--beautiful-swan-beautiful-birds.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/1f/fa/4c/1ffa4c7d4f977a9c43c5655a4a3ea0ab--fox-baby-pet-fox.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/1c/9e/e1/1c9ee1aba651fde0473a4abcc8cab6c4--baby-cheetahs-travel-photography.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/fd/cd/40/fdcd40daae027c7f51298a543a015791--baby-caracal-baby-bobcat.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/cc/75/b7/cc75b77d9cea128fcab6daa1d57826af--leopard-animal-baby-leopard.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/3c/93/29/3c9329976aa40675483e026f4ac5baa6--animaux-totems-can-to.jpg
```